# Keyboard not resigning when viewcontroller is popped from the navigation controller

Tags: iphone

I am facing a problem in resigning the keyboard. i have a `tableViewController` in a navigation controller and a different view controller is pushed to the navigation controller on selection of one of the cell. in the view controller i have assigned a textfield as the first responder so that the keyboard shows up as soon as viewcontroller is pushed and the keyboard is resigned while popping the viewcontroller

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

this is working fine when. But again when I push the same view controller and when I pop it the keyboard is not resigning. It is blocking the view of the tableViewController.

Comment: a few guesses: 
1. your textField is not actually the first responder
2. You didn't connect the textField to an outlet and it's nil.

How about using a breakpoint in viewWillDisappear to make sure it's called, and make sure self.textField is indeed what you think it is.

Comment: hi Ron...
i checked whether the textField is the first responder using the code [textField isFirstResponder] and this is returning YES. [textField resignFirstResponder] is also returning YES the second time when i pop the view controller but the keyboard is not hiding.

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem than you with the same context (UINavigationController, UIAlertView, UITextField or UITextView).

I solved this problem easily by executing the pop in background and remove the resignFirstResponder call (viewWillDisappear method in your file) like this :

```
-(void)popCurrentView {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (alertView.cancelButtonIndex != buttonIndex) {
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(popCurrentView) withObject:nil]; 
    }
}
```